# Prove that rank of 3 by 3 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that rank of 3 by 3 matrix C=(AB)which is obtained by multiplying a non zero columm matrix A of size 3 by 1 and a non zero row matrix B of size 1 by 3 is 1.

My attempt :
I didn't go for a formal proof,  but rather verified it by taking 2 non zero matrices as a example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c \end{pmatrix},B=\begin{pmatrix}d&e&f \end{pmatrix}$, then $C=AB=\begin{pmatrix}ad&ae&af\\bd&be&bf\\cd&ce&cf \end{pmatrix}$. Then column $2$ is $\frac{e}{d}$ times column $1$ and column $3$ is $\frac{f}{d}$ times column $1$. So therefore, $C$ has rank $1$.

Answer (score 1):

The rows of $C$ will be the multiples of $B$, which is a single row vector, and hence the rows of $C$ are in the linear space spanned by $B$, $Span(B)$ which has dimension $1$, assuming $B$ is non-zero. The columns of $C$ will be the multiples of $A$, which is a single column vector, and hence the columns of $C$ belong to $Span(A)$ which also has dimension $1$, assuming $A$ is non-zero.